# Django: user info in template

Tags: django-templates

I have this in my base.html template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p style="color:#000;">
    Welcome
    {{ user.first_name }}
    | 
    <a href="/logout/">Logout</a>
</p>
{% endif %}
```

After I authenticate, and go to this page, my first name does not show up. Can anybody tell me why?

The "Welcome" also does not show up. So, this must be failing on `user.is_authenticated`.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Does the `Welcome` show up at all, or does it not meet the condition?

Comment: Make sure you're not overwriting the variable 'user' on the Context passed to your template. Besides that, check if you're really logged in and your user have a first_name ;-)

Comment: Welcome also does not show up.

Comment: jweyrich, overwrite? Hmmm... The view does not return anything but load this page. I thought user was globally available. No?

Comment: it is available as 'request.user' within the controller. You need to pass it to your template. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` middleware is responsible for setting `request.user` before a request reaches the controller.

In order to access it from a template, you need to pass this variable or a `RequestContext`. Example:

```
def something(request):
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    template_name = 'your_template.html'
    extra_context = { 'other_variable': 'some value' }
    return render_to_response(template_name, extra_context, context_instance)
```

This way, all the request variables are accessible from the template.

Comment: I have the same issue, but my that templates is base templates, by your method i have to pass it on every childe page's view?

Comment: @MuhammadTaqiHassanBukhari: You may write a function that hides these details, so instead of calling `render_to_response`, you'd call your own function that has all this logic.